# aligning multiple div headings in same height

Tags: html, css

I'm writing an HTML page that has 3 divs in it. and each div has a heading and a para. currently, the para is getting aligned as per the heading content height. How can I make sure that the paras in all the divs start at the same position irrespective of the h2 content?

Here is my current code.

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
 }

.child{
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.child h2{
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  min-height: max-content;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
     <h2>Proper heading with more co</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam,</p>
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     <h2>large heading that is bigger than proper heading</h2>
     <p>labore odio minima cumque molestiae amet vitae! Voluptatum</p>
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     <h2>small</h2>
     <p>
       cupiditate unde vel culpa veritatis eius dicta, quia, quas dolores
       similique hic! Iure.
     </p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you set the height of h2 to a specific value, it will be right!
for example:

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
 }

.child{
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.child h2{
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  height: 60px;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
     <h2>Proper heading with more co</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam,</p>
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     <h2>large heading that is bigger than proper heading</h2>
     <p>labore odio minima cumque molestiae amet vitae! Voluptatum</p>
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     <h2>small</h2>
     <p>
       cupiditate unde vel culpa veritatis eius dicta, quia, quas dolores
       similique hic! Iure.
     </p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The content is overlapped.